# Concerning "else" statement in for-loop when traversing through array

Tags: java, for-loop, traversal

I'm trying to solve a problem where I need to find all the **even numbers only**. I need to input 5 numbers, and if none of the numbers are even I want to print **Even number not found in array.**
So my problem is when I iterate through the for-loop, my code prints **Even number not found in array.** It prints for each non-even number, which is not what its suppose to do obviously. I need some kind of hint. This is not homework btw, it is a problem found on Programmr.com. Here is my code:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class ArrayEven {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
     @SuppressWarnings("resource")
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     int x, arr[] = new int[5];

     for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       arr[i] = scanner.nextInt();
       if (i == 4)
         break;

    }

     for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

       x = arr[i] % 2;

       if (x == 0) {

         System.out.println(arr[i]);

       }

       else if (x != 0) {  //this is obviously wrong. Do I need another for-loop for this?

         System.out.println("Even number not found in array.");

       }

     }

   }

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `boolean` here,
Initialize `boolean` variable with `false`
if you found any `even` than set the `boolean` as `true`
and check that `boolean` in your `if` condiion.

Example :

```
boolean isAvailble = false;
...
// Some code
...
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       x = arr[i] % 2;
       if (x == 0) {
         System.out.println(arr[i]);
         isAvailble = true;
       }
}

if (! isAvailable) {  
     System.out.println("Even number not found in array.");
}
```

Comment: You guys are awesome. It works and actually makes alot of sense now.

Comment: Pleasure that we can help someone...:)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
 @SuppressWarnings("resource")
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 int x, arr[] = new int[5];

 for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   arr[i] = scanner.nextInt();
   if (i == 4)
     break;

}
boolean evenFound = false; 

 for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

   x = arr[i] % 2;

   if (x == 0) {

     System.out.println(arr[i]);
     evenFound = true; 

   }

 }
 if(!evenFound){
     System.out.println("Not found");

  }
```

}